# zf2 new module controller resolves to invalid controller class or alias when using factories

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the following in my application module config:

```
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Application\Controller\IndexController::class => Application\Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class
        ],
    ],
```

this works fine. now im my `serve module` i have pretty much the same:

```
'controllers' => array(
                    /**
                    'invokables' => array(
                            'Serve\Controller\Index' => 'Serve\Controller\IndexController',
                    ),
                    */

                    'factories' => array(
                            Controller\IndexController::class => Serve\Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class
                    )

            ),
```

when i load the homepage i access through an api the serve controller. when doing so i get this problem on the homepage:

`Serve\Controller\Index (resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Serve\Controller\Index)`

like i said im accessing the serve controller through an api so it might be a setup issue when requesting through the system as an api.

Whats interesting is when i do this it works:

```
'controllers'=>array(
    'invokables' => array(
                    'Serve\Controller\Index' => 'Serve\Controller\IndexController',
            )),
```

not sure whats wrong here

UPDATE:

This seems to work:

```
'factories' => array(
                    'Serve\Controller\Index' => IndexControllerFactory::class
            )
```

however id like to use `::class` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within your route config as you map to the controller: `Serve\Controller\Index` but you either never registered that controller with that specific key within your `module.config` or you are using the wrong value for the key "*controller*" within your route as you specified the FQCN within your controller mapping.

```php
// module.config
'aliases' => [
    'Serve\Controller\Index' => Serve\Controller\IndexController:class,
],
'factories' => [
    Serve\Controller\IndexController:class => Serve\Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
],
```

Or within your route configs don't use the `Serve\Controller\Index` but use the FQCN, so that it uses the Factory directly instead of the alias you've set up. Like:

```
// route.config
'serve' => [
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/serve',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Serve\Controller\IndexController::class,
            'action'     => 'index',
       ],
    ],
],
```

I keep mapping my classes in the factory mapping with the FQCN and add aliases if I want to call them by another name. So you are now able to either use the FQCN or any of its aliases, like: `Serve\Controller\Index`

Comment: Thanks man. Solved the issue for me.